# X-Pages: fileUpload control preventing unwanted files from being uploaded

Tags: xpages

I am using the accept property in the `fileUpload` control to only allow certain file Types and prevent uploading .exe or other potentially harmful files.

```
application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,application/pdf,text/plain,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png"
```

This works, however I am using a Tool called Burp Suite that allows me to intercept an acceptable file eg `.txt` that could contain harmful code and change the filename extension to `.exe` which is then upload to the X-Page database.

When I goto save the document and after Interception and changing to a .exe, I have added the following code to identify an exe file:
Can we manipulate what has been uploaded and change the file extension to a harmless .txt ?

```
 var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile =facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameterMap().get(getClientId('fileUpload1'));

if (fileData != null) {
    var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();
    // Get the path
    var filePath:String = tempFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
    // Get file Name
    var fileName:String = tempFile.getParentFile().getName();
    // Get the Name of the file as it appeared on the client machine - the name on the server will NOT be the same
    var clientFileName:String = fileData.getClientFileName();

}
var fileRight = clientFileName.slice(-4);
if (fileRight == ".exe")
{   
//facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameterMap().get(getClientId('fileUpload1').replace(".exe",".txt"))
//facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameterMap().get(getClientId('fileUpload1').remove(".exe",0))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have on the properties of control two options 'Use original file name of uploaded file' and 'Replace file name of uploaded file...' where you can put name with extension 'name.txt' . I didn't try to change only extension... That is probably better in code to replace.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much , I used this solution you provided and it worked.